# How to deserialize this json

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is the json response returned by MediaWiki API. I want to create a class to be able to deserialize it to it use Jackson library. The problem is that this json contains a key which is different from each request (here is 290).

```
{
    "query-continue": {
        "revisions": {
            "rvcontinue": 633308090
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "290": {
                "pageid": 290,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "A",
                "revisions": [
                    {
                        "user": "Mr. Guye",
                        "timestamp": "2014-12-07T17:45:55Z",
                        "comment": "comment",
                        "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
                        "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                        "*": "content"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could create  a class (or configure the mapper) to be able to deserialize this json?

Comment: First get the keys, and then look for that keys in a second pass. Each time you go deep and there is a key, its an another pass, until there are no keys. So you will make an array of keys

Answer (score 2):

You can deserialize JSON to multiple formats using Jackson. One way that you mentioned is to convert the JSON to a POJO which may be difficult when the keys are dynamic. Another approach is to deserialize the JSON to the Jackson Tree Model which is called `JsonNode`. The following illustrates how you can parse the provided JSON to a `JsonNode` and then retrieve the various attributes.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Parse the JSON, deserialize to the Tree Model
final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

// Get hold of the "query -> pages" node.
final JsonNode pages = jsonNode.path("query").path("pages");

// Iterate the pages
for (final JsonNode page : pages) {
    // Work with the page object here...
    System.out.println(page.get("pageid")); // -> 290
}
```

The `JsonNode` object is very flexible and contains various convenience functions for accessing the data. As shown in the example above the `path()` and `get()` methods are two ways of accessing the data. If you use `get()` the property MUST exist, if you use `path` the property MAY exist. Furthermore, there are multiple ways of iterating the sub-elements and the loop shown above is one way.

Take a look at the [Jackson docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) for more info.

Comment: Yep, excellent suggestion and this is definitely another way to go.  He can also combine our approaches and create the POJO the way I described, and then use your suggestion to just query for the * content and set it into the POJO.

Comment: @TheSaint, the asterisk is not a problem if you use `@JsonProperty("*")`. The problem lies in parsing the dynamic data where you don't  actually know the property names ("290" in the example).

Comment: Yep, I see it now.  Good work and explanation by yourself and @extraleon.

Comment: Although @wassgren's solution is a valid one, I think that from the presented json format and fields naming it can be deduced that field 'pages' is like an associative array of  format { "dynamic page id" : "static typed page object",...} . In this case creating a POJO with a map for 'pages' field seems to be more straightforward than iterating over tree of JsonNodes.

Comment: @extraleon Ageeed, a POJO with a dynamic page field. Just trying to show that `JsonNode` is flexible and can be used for this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't, at least not in the current format with that abominable asterisk being present.  Therefore, we will have to employ a bit of hackery here to get the job done, and I warn you upfront, it's not going to be pretty.

Firstly, copy that response, then go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and paste it into the JSON textbox.  After pasting it, change the asterisk to something more civilized, like "content".  Select JSON (default is JSON Schema) for the Source Type, input your package and root class name respectively, and click JAR to generate the package with all the POJO's that map to this JSON.  You could also click "Preview" and copy paste the code into your source files -- it's really up to you.

Now that we have a valid version of this JSON structure, we use Jackson to read it in.  If your JSON String is called jsonResponse and the corresponding POJO class is MediaWiki, then you convert it with Jackson like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
MediaWiki mw = objectMapper.readValue(profileJson, MediaWiki.class);
```

The key here is the FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES being set to false, which means it will ignore that asterisk, and create everything else for you.

Now, to actually grab whatever value was present for that asterisk and store it into our "content" attribute (or whatever else you wanted replace the asterisk with), you are going to have to parse this sucker out client-side and pass it as a separate input parameter, and to do that, you will have to yank it out by calling something like this:

```
var content = query.pages.290.revisions["*"];
```

This content parameter is passed and stored it into your POJO's content attribute.

I know it's a lot of work, and if anyone else has a more elegant solution, please share.  As I said, mine was not going to be pretty. :-)

Comment: Asterisk is not an issue. Might be easily parsed by means of Jackson json annotation   @JsonProperty("*")  String asterisk;

Comment: Not true.  Asterisk is very much the issue when attempting to convert the asterisk into an actual Java variable name because * is a reserved Java keyword.  In other words, you cannot have a String called * in a Java class, which is why if you copy the JSON response as-is and try to generate POJO classes on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, you will get an internal server error.

Comment: I agree you can't have variable named * in java. That's why there is a Jackson annotation I've mentioned. This way you don't need to name variable "*" in Java POJO but you can give it any name you like instead.  Jsonschema2pojo.org POJO generator that you mentioned is limited tool and apparently doesn't handle such cases. Solution that you provided is much more complicated than just adding annotation to a field.

Comment: @extraleon, exactly. Good point!. The OP:s problem is rather to parse "dynamic fields" such as the "290".

Comment: Ahh, I see now what you are saying. If we add the @JsonProperty("*") to the content variable (or whatever else you want to call it), the value will convert and there is no need to perform the second part of my answer.  Although, as @wassgren mentioned, this is an issue with parsing dynamic keys, so the least path of resistance is to use the Jackson Tree model, although that will require a lot of iteration through the nodes.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like key value pair.
You can use map in order to deserialize key value pairs:

```
public class Query {

   private Map<Integer, Page> pages;

   public Map<Integer, Page> getPages() {
      return pages;
   }

   public void setPages(Map<Integer, Page> pages) {
      this.pages = pages;
   }
}
```

Jackson handles such deserialization by default.